# rspec mailer test with objects passed to mail method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mailer

My rails application sends emails and the mailer methods require objects to be passed in as shown in the following code for the evidence_added_email method:

```
class EvidenceMailer < ApplicationMailer
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

def evidence_added_email(evidence, current_user, root_url)
  @evidence = Evidence.find(evidence)
  @root_url = root_url
  recipients = User.where(is_auditor: true).map {|u| u.email }
  blind_copy_recipients = User.where(receive_notifications: true).map {|u| u.email }
  subject = 'SGPLAN: Evidência de ' + @evidence.milestone.manager.user_name + ' adicionada'
  mail(to: recipients, bcc: blind_copy_recipients, from: current_user.email, subject: subject)
end

def test_email
  mail(to: 'to@example.com', from: 'from@example.com', subject: 'Test Subject')
end
```

The passed in evidence parameter/object requires the creation of a number of other objects. So the test spec looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe EvidenceMailer, type: :mailer do
  FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
  Agency.current = Agency.find_by(initials: 'SECTI').id
  FactoryGirl.create(:department)
  FactoryGirl.create(:first_plan)
  Plan.current = Plan.find_by(name: 'first').id
  FactoryGirl.create(:project)
  FactoryGirl.create(:milestone)
  FactoryGirl.create(:evidence)

  describe "evidence added email" do
    let(:mail) { EvidenceMailer.evidence_added_email(Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence').id,
                                                     User.find_by(email: 'admin@example.com'),
                                                     '/test_root_url') }
    it "renders the headers" do
      expect(mail.subject).to include("SGPLAN")
    end
  end

  describe "test email" do
    let(:mail) { EvidenceMailer.test_email }
    it "renders the headers" do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq('Test Subject')
    end
  end
end
```

The test email example passes but the evidence added example fails with the following error:

```
1) EvidenceMailer evidence added email renders the headers
     Failure/Error:
       let(:mail) { EvidenceMailer.evidence_added_email(Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence').id,
                                                        User.find_by(email: 'admin@example.com'),
                                                        '/test_root_url') }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/mailers/evidence_notifications_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/mailers/evidence_notifications_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If I execute the spec file by stepping through it with a debugger, it appears that the describe loops are each executed twice. The first time they are executed the Evidence object and all of the other objects exist but the EvidenceMailer method is not executed. The second time the objects no longer exist but the EvidenceMailer.test_email method is executed and that test passes.

I'm relatively new to rails and testing with rspec and haven't found any examples of rspec tests where parameters need to be passed into the mailer method. We're retrofitting tests to some parts of our application and I know that the evidence_added_email functionality actually works.

Our environment is as follows:

```
capybara (2.7.1)
poltergeist (1.6.0)
database_cleaner (1.5.3)
factory_girl_rails (4.7.0)
rails (4.2.5)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-rails (3.5.2)
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
postgresql
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get this test working?

**Update**

The factory for evidence is as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :evidence do
    name 'Test Evidence'
    before(:create) do |evidence|
      evidence.milestone = Milestone.find_or_create_by(title: 'Test Milestone')
      evidence.plan = Plan.find_or_create_by(name: 'first')
      evidence.agency = Agency.find_or_create_by(initials: 'SECTI')
    end
  end
end
```

I added some output statements as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe EvidenceMailer, type: :mailer do
  ...
  puts "First #{Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence').id}"

  describe "evidence added email" do
    puts "Second #{Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence').id}"
    ...
  end

  describe "test email" do
    puts "Third #{Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence').id}"
    ...
  end
end
```

with the following result at the console

```
First 1
Second 1
Third 1
F.

Failures:

  1) EvidenceMailer evidence added email renders the headers
     Failure/Error:
       let(:mail) {    EvidenceMailer.evidence_added_email(Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence').id,
                                                        User.find_by(email: 'admin@example.com'),
                                                        '/test_root_url') }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/mailers/evidence_notifications_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/mailers/evidence_notifications_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So Evidence.find_by is successful in one place but not the other.

Comment: It looks like `Evidence.find_by(name: 'Test Evidence')` is returning `nil`. Can you include the source code for your Evidence factory?

Comment: Actually, all the file building should be in a `before do`  `end` block.

Comment: If I put the file building in a before do end block, the test fails at the first puts statement in the above update (indicating that Evidence.find_by returns nil). Without the block it is successful as shown in the update.